# Charging battery simultaneously from 2 sources

Tags: batteries, charger

This is my first time posting here.
I have an issue, I want to charge battery from 2 sources simultaneously, but I am kinda a worried about how that might work.
If I add the voltage feedback directly to battery then one charger might trick other charger. I guess I could put diodes, but I have a feeling this might make me another trouble. Of course instead of diodes I can use Mosfets for lower power losses in this load sharing.

[image]
Have any of you guys tried something like this? Any advises?

Comment: One charger will always win the battle and supply most (nearly all) the charging current.

Comment: what kind of battery? What kind of charger? Have seen charging protocols that charge with constant current until a target voltage is reached, whence they switch to a "maintain" protocol. Charger manuals often don't tell you what protocols are employed.

Comment: @glen_geek I don't still have not decided the battery chemistry, but probably Li-ion or Lead acid.  at the moment I have made charger based on LTC4012-2 and LTC4079, but I still have not decided what IC I will use for chargers in this solution

Comment: I am currently involved in such a design, and basically you have to give priority to one source and when that cannot supply the current needed then the other takes over. So you need current and voltage feedback to a supervisor type device.

Comment: Since you must have constant current limiting on your chargers, they will work in prefect paralell during the bulk charging phase. Once you reach the CV part of it, one will win but at this point you have already gained whatever charging time you where after in the first place. The diode will drop some voltage though.

Answer (score 1):

Current shared Voltage regulators that do not sense remotely are inherently stable with Diode OR isolation.  ( high supply delivers the current.)

- Other related info but same as your situation

Unlike above Current Shared  DC supplies with shared remote sensing must be balanced within 10% typically and often require a preload of 10% to be stable due to change in loop gain high low load.

I recall 20 yrs ago in RB, Cali,USA (Unisys Server factory) we had redundant Current shared dual supplies with major brand OEM source who had to come out and view stability oscillation for themselves to know their design failed without a 10% preload, so we added this to the Production initial HASS test process.

Comment: Thanks for info! I am not experienced so can you please tell me little bit more- what do you mean by "do not sense remotely". Are you referring to voltage feedback for Voltage regulator?
I guess I will have to read about preload, because I don't know what is meant by that.

Comment: yes voltage sensing after diode at battery = "remote" ,   preload = dummy load  to ensure stability with no battery connected. It can be much smaller than 10% in a good design with high gain margin over no-full load range. Often smart chargers use Vsense , Isense at output to disable charger. Then apply pulses to assess ESR of battery and SoC then full CC

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are developing those chargers then what they need is not a voltage feedback, but rather an output current feedback.

This way you'd have a control loop that measures the output current and, assuming the charger is some kind of SMPS, the duty cycle would be adjusted to keep the output current constant. This means that the chargers would pretty much balance out their currents without problems.

Of course, when the battery starts to get to 100% charge, you need to go into constant voltage (CV) mode, and when this happens the currents involved will typically be small in relation to what you had before going into CV mode, so it wouldn't matter which charger supplies the current, as long as the charger is protected against reverse current.

And by the way, some SMPSs are inherently protected against reverse currents due to their topology. For instance, if those chargers are boost converters, then you don't need to be worried about one charger trying to "charge" the other one, because the boost topology already uses a diode directly at the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you diode OR the DC supplies and use one charger? Advantages:

1. Most chargers can take a wide input voltage with no problems.
2. If your charger is switch-mode and DC input is higher, then the current is lower through your diodes by putting diodes on the input side.
3. Saves you the cost of another charger

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flwC5I.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>